# Interesting regex replace 3 digits while retaining other 3 digits in same line

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I am looking to replace below line which has two strings using linux **sed** (open for using other linux commands)

> VENDORTIME = 20170525-09:30:18.203, PRICE = 53.631,
>
> PRICE = 53.631, VENDORTIME = 20170525-09:30:18.203,

with

> VENDORTIME = 20170525-09:30:18.**000**, PRICE = 53.631,
>
> PRICE = 53.631, VENDORTIME = 20170525-09:30:18.**000**,

meanwhile I have to retain PRICE = 53.631, **NOT** to be replaced by **53.000**

I tried `sed -r 's/\.([0-9]){3},/.000,/g'` but it replaces PRICE key as well.

I tried `sed -r 's/:([0-9]){2}\.([0-9]){3},/.000,/g'` but it replaces VENDORTIME loosing some data while not touching PRICE key

Comment: To make it safer, use `'s/(VENDORTIME *= *[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\.[0-9]+,/\1.000,/g'` (it will work [like this](https://regex101.com/r/704rcr/1)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
s='VENDORTIME = 20170525-09:30:18.203, PRICE = 53.631,'
sed -E 's/(VENDORTIME[ \t]*=[ \t]*[0-9:-]+)\.[0-9]{3},/\1.000,/' <<< "$s"

VENDORTIME = 20170525-09:30:18.000, PRICE = 53.631,
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava. But I also have 10k lines (with vendortime and price) like this in my file.

Comment: I understood your solution(replace is first matched string per line) but what happens if I have PRICE field before VENDORTIME in my line?

Comment: no offense I wasnt trying to shoot your answer down but I got this follow up question after understanding your solution.

Comment: thanks. out of curiousity what is the meaning of  <<< "$s"

Comment: That is called here string.  The part after `<<<` (in this case `$s`) is  supplied  as  a single string to the `sed` command on its standard input.

Comment: Understood. Can you please clarify how the replace string in sed /\1.000, just replaces milliseconds portion of time and not the whole find match (VENDORTIME[ \t]*=[ \t]*[0-9:-]+)\.[0-9]{3},

Comment: It is because we are capturing text using `(...)` and `\1` is back-reference of the first captured group. When we use `\1` in replacement that means we are putting back text captured in 1st capturing group.

Comment: [Check this helpful documentation on capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just removing the `g`lobal flag from your `sed` command would have been enough if the `VENDORTIME` had always came first : that way, `sed` would have only performed one substitution by line, replacing the `VENDORTIME` but not the `PRICE`.

Since you can have those in both orders, you can match a little bit more from your line :

```
s/(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.)\d{3}/\1000/
```

It would now match a full `HH:MM:SS.sss`, capture the `HH:MM:SS.` part in a group and replace the whole matched string by the grouped part (referenced by `\1`) followed by 000.

Comment: I understood your solution(replace is first matched string per line) but what happens if I have PRICE field before VENDORTIME in my line?

Comment: @SrujanKumarGulla then it wouldn't work, but I've just edited my answer to provide a solution to these cases :)

Comment: @SrujanKumarGulla and edited it again because I had forgotten to use a back-reference